# How to modify the Orientation exif tag in a jpg file without changing anything else in the file, using Winforms C# or C++ .Net

Tags: c#, c++, jpeg, orientation, exif

I'm writing a program to help my organise the thousands of digital photos I have taken over the years. One feature I want is to be able to rotate an image by modifying the Orientation EXIF tag, without changing anything else in the file. I KNOW this is possible because if you right-click on the file in Windows Explorer and select Rotate Left/Right then exactly that happens - one byte is modified to match the new orientation value. I specifically do NOT want to modify the picture itself.

However everything I have tried either has no effect or significantly changes the file (e.g. reduces it by 14k bytes, presumably by re-encoding it). I have read many posts on several websites and nobody seems to have an answer about my specific problem - mostly they talk about adding extra tags, and the need to add padding, but surely I don't need to add padding if I'm only trying to modify one existing byte (especially as I know that Windows Explorer can do it).

I'm using a C# Windows Forms application running Framework 4.5.2 under Windows 10 Pro. Also tried doing it from C++. Thanks to all the contributors whose examples I have built upon.

Here are 5 bare-bones console app examples :

1. Basic C# using System.Drawing.Image class. This sets the Orientation tag OK but reduces the size i.e. re-encodes the picture.

   ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int EXIF_ORIENTATION = 0x0112;

        try
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile("Test.jpg"))
            {
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem orientation = image.GetPropertyItem(EXIF_ORIENTATION);

                byte o = 6; // Rotate 90 degrees clockwise

                orientation.Value[0] = o;

                image.SetPropertyItem(orientation);

                image.Save("Test2.jpg");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
   ```
2. The InPlaceBitMapEditor class looks like a exactly what I need, and the debug lines suggest this is modifying the EXIF tag, but the file is not modified i.e. the changes not written out.

   ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream("Test.JPG", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            JpegBitmapDecoder pngDecoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

            BitmapFrame frame = pngDecoder.Frames[0];

            InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter inplace = frame.CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter();

            ushort u = 6; // Rotate 90 degrees clockwise

            object i1 = inplace.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=274}"); // DEBUG - this is what it was before - 1

            if (inplace.TrySave() == true)
            {
                inplace.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=274}", u);
            }

            object i2 = inplace.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=274}"); // DEBUG - this is what it is after - 6

            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
   ```
3. An evolution of the above, which explicitly writes out the file. This sets the Orientation tag and the file displays OK but reduces the size i.e. re-encodes the picture.

   ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;

        using (Stream originalFile = File.Open("Test.JPG", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            BitmapDecoder original = BitmapDecoder.Create(originalFile, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None);

            if (!original.CodecInfo.FileExtensions.Contains("jpg"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file you passed in is not a JPEG.");
                return;
            }

            JpegBitmapEncoder output = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

            BitmapFrame frame = original.Frames[0];

            BitmapMetadata metadata = frame.Metadata.Clone() as BitmapMetadata;

            ushort u = 6;

            object i1 = metadata.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=274}"); // DEBUG - this is what it was before - 1

            metadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=274}", u);

            object i2 = metadata.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=274}"); // DEBUG - this is what it was after - 6

            output.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(original.Frames[0], original.Frames[0].Thumbnail, metadata, original.Frames[0].ColorContexts));


            using (Stream outputFile = File.Open("Test2.JPG", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                output.Save(outputFile);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Tried using C++ instead, with some alternate techniques using GDI+.  This sets the Orientation tag OK but reduces the size i.e. re-encodes the picture.

   ```
    // ConsoleApplication4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"

    #include <windows.h>
    #include <gdiplus.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace Gdiplus;

    /*
    This rotates the file and saves under a different name, but the file size has been shrunk by 18 KB from 3446 KB to 3428 KB
    */


    int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
    {
        UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
        UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

        ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

        GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
        if (size == 0)
            return -1;  // Failure

        pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
        if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
            return -1;  // Failure

        GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

        for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
        {
            if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
            {
                *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
                free(pImageCodecInfo);
                return j;  // Success
            }
        }

        free(pImageCodecInfo);
        return -1;  // Failure
    }

    int RotateImage()
    {
        // Initialize <tla rid="tla_gdiplus"/>.
        GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
        ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
        GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
        Status stat;
        CLSID  clsid;
        unsigned short v;

        Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(L"Test.JPG");
        PropertyItem* propertyItem = new PropertyItem;

        // Get the CLSID of the JPEG encoder.
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
        propertyItem->id = PropertyTagOrientation;
        propertyItem->length = 2;  // string length including NULL terminator
        propertyItem->type = PropertyTagTypeShort;

        v = 6; // Rotate 90 degrees clockwise
        propertyItem->value = &v;
        bitmap->SetPropertyItem(propertyItem);
        stat = bitmap->Save(L"Test2.JPG", &clsid, NULL);

        if (stat != Ok) printf("Error saving.\n");

        delete propertyItem;
        delete bitmap;
        GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        RotateImage();

        return 0;
    }
   ```
5. This is a whopper and fairly low-level. This sets the Orientation tag OK but reduces the size i.e. re-encodes the picture.

   ```
    // ConsoleApplication5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"

    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <wincodecsdk.h>

    /*
    This rotates the file and saves under a different name, but the file size has been shrunk by 18 KB from 3446 KB to 3428 KB
    */

    int RotateImage()
    {
        // Initialize COM.
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

        IWICImagingFactory *piFactory = NULL;
        IWICBitmapDecoder *piDecoder = NULL;

        // Create the COM imaging factory.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
                NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                IID_PPV_ARGS(&piFactory));
        }

        // Create the decoder.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = piFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(L"Test.JPG", NULL, GENERIC_READ,
                WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, //For JPEG lossless decoding/encoding.
                &piDecoder);
        }

        // Variables used for encoding.
        IWICStream *piFileStream = NULL;
        IWICBitmapEncoder *piEncoder = NULL;
        IWICMetadataBlockWriter *piBlockWriter = NULL;
        IWICMetadataBlockReader *piBlockReader = NULL;

        WICPixelFormatGUID pixelFormat = { 0 };
        UINT count = 0;
        double dpiX, dpiY = 0.0;
        UINT width, height = 0;

        // Create a file stream.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = piFactory->CreateStream(&piFileStream);
        }

        // Initialize our new file stream.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = piFileStream->InitializeFromFilename(L"Test2.jpg", GENERIC_WRITE);
        }

        // Create the encoder.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = piFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, NULL, &piEncoder);
        }
        // Initialize the encoder
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = piEncoder->Initialize(piFileStream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = piDecoder->GetFrameCount(&count);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Process each frame of the image.
            for (UINT i = 0; i < count &&SUCCEEDED(hr); i++)
            {
                // Frame variables.
                IWICBitmapFrameDecode *piFrameDecode = NULL;
                IWICBitmapFrameEncode *piFrameEncode = NULL;
                IWICMetadataQueryReader *piFrameQReader = NULL;
                IWICMetadataQueryWriter *piFrameQWriter = NULL;

                // Get and create the image frame.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piDecoder->GetFrame(i, &piFrameDecode);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&piFrameEncode, NULL);
                }

                // Initialize the encoder.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameEncode->Initialize(NULL);
                }
                // Get and set the size.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameDecode->GetSize(&width, &height);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameEncode->SetSize(width, height);
                }
                // Get and set the resolution.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    piFrameDecode->GetResolution(&dpiX, &dpiY);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameEncode->SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);
                }
                // Set the pixel format.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    piFrameDecode->GetPixelFormat(&pixelFormat);
                }
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameEncode->SetPixelFormat(&pixelFormat);
                }

                // Check that the destination format and source formats are the same.
                bool formatsEqual = FALSE;
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    GUID srcFormat;
                    GUID destFormat;

                    hr = piDecoder->GetContainerFormat(&srcFormat);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        hr = piEncoder->GetContainerFormat(&destFormat);
                    }
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        if (srcFormat == destFormat)
                            formatsEqual = true;
                        else
                            formatsEqual = false;
                    }
                }

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && formatsEqual)
                {
                    // Copy metadata using metadata block reader/writer.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        piFrameDecode->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&piBlockReader));
                    }
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        piFrameEncode->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&piBlockWriter));
                    }
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        piBlockWriter->InitializeFromBlockReader(piBlockReader);
                    }
                }

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameEncode->GetMetadataQueryWriter(&piFrameQWriter);
                }

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // Set Orientation.
                    PROPVARIANT    value;
                    value.vt = VT_UI2;
                    value.uiVal = 6; // Rotate 90 degrees clockwise
                    hr = piFrameQWriter->SetMetadataByName(L"/app1/ifd/{ushort=274}", &value);
                }

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameEncode->WriteSource(
                        static_cast<IWICBitmapSource*> (piFrameDecode),
                        NULL); // Using NULL enables JPEG loss-less encoding.
                }

                // Commit the frame.
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = piFrameEncode->Commit();
                }

                if (piFrameDecode)
                {
                    piFrameDecode->Release();
                }

                if (piFrameEncode)
                {
                    piFrameEncode->Release();
                }

                if (piFrameQReader)
                {
                    piFrameQReader->Release();
                }

                if (piFrameQWriter)
                {
                    piFrameQWriter->Release();
                }
            }
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            piEncoder->Commit();
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            piFileStream->Commit(STGC_DEFAULT);
        }

        if (piFileStream)
        {
            piFileStream->Release();
        }
        if (piEncoder)
        {
            piEncoder->Release();
        }
        if (piBlockWriter)
        {
            piBlockWriter->Release();
        }
        if (piBlockReader)
        {
            piBlockReader->Release();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        RotateImage();

        return 0;
    }
   ```

Again, there are a lot of posts on various sites that are similar but not close enough, and I have tried to apply what they suggest with no success.  Please accept my apologies if this has indeed been answered elsewhere.

I know I can just live with the slight change to the file, and once it has been changed once it doesn't seem to get changed again - if I rotate the file by 90 degrees 5 times then it produces the same binary as if I rotate just once, but I can't see why it changes at all, if all I want to do is modify the orientation tag, and I know that's possible because Windows Explorer can do it !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I suggest not to confuse 'changing file size' and 're-encoding'. File size may also be reduced by writing a smaller version of exif or other meta data. A pixel exact comparison of the image data would be recommended.

Comment: @Some: This is a well wrtitten and excellently researched question. None of your points apply, least of all hinting at the debugger..!

Comment: @Some: thanks for the advice about how to debug programs. In 41 years of personal and professional software development, I've never been told to explain my code to a rubber duck, but I do appreciate that sometimes working through it in basic terms helps highlight the issue. Didn't help me in this case though.

Comment: @TaW: Yes, I suspected you're right about it not actually re-encoding the image. So I wrote a quick prog to compare the file backwards from the end, and indeed the last 99% or so is identical. So maybe it's just removing some padding or something ?  This means I can live with it as it's not degrading the actual picture quality, but I'd still love to know why the in-place-edit class isn't working (number 2. above).  Oh, and thanks for the vote of confidence - I spent a few hours distilling my attempts into simple examples and it's good to know it was noticed :)

Comment: I woudn't be amazed, esp. with all those tagging adventures I've been through with audio files and their tags. It would be interesting to learn about any differences between the five test programms you wrote. Testing this way (binary I guess) is fast and simple; comparing the pixels themselves is maybe even more convincing and with lockbits should also be fast..

Comment: It looks like they all have changes in the first 1% and nothing else, but they're all slightly different to each other. I did just google around a bit to see if the EncoderParameters for a jpg encoder allowed you to say "don't mess with the metadata" but couldn't find anything except to set quality level.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this programatically is to read the APP1 marker that should come after the SOS market. Get the JPEG documentation for the marker structure.

Once you have the APP1 marker, you need to change the orientation however you want it.

Then write an SOS marker, your modified APP1 marker, and the rest of the JPEG stream after the APP1 marker to a new file.

That's all their is to it. The only complexity is navigating the EXIF documentation to do the orientation setting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this unless jpeg's width and height are both multiple of 16. If this operation is done in GDI+, and width and height are not multiple of 16, GDI+ will do its best to keep the compression quality the same. It's the same in .net

See also 
[Transforming a JPEG Image Without Loss of Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-transforming-a-jpeg-image-without-loss-of-information-use)

Note, your GDI+ code will only rotate the thumbnail. To rotate the image, use the code below:

```
void RotateImage()
{
    //new/delete operator is not necessary, unless 
    //Gdiplus startup/shutdown is in the same scope
    Gdiplus::Image image(L"source.jpg");
    if((image.GetWidth() % 16) != 0 || (image.GetHeight() % 16) != 0)
        wprintf(L"Lossless compression is not possible\n");

    Gdiplus::EncoderParameters encoder_params;
    encoder_params.Count = 1;
    encoder_params.Parameter[0].Guid = Gdiplus::EncoderTransformation;
    encoder_params.Parameter[0].Type = Gdiplus::EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
    encoder_params.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;

    //rotate
    ULONG transformation = Gdiplus::EncoderValueTransformRotate90;
    encoder_params.Parameter[0].Value = &transformation;

    CLSID clsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
    auto stat = image.Save(L"destination.jpg", &clsid, &encoder_params);

    wprintf(L"Save %s\n", (stat == Gdiplus::Ok) ? L"succeeded" : L"failed");
}

int main()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    RotateImage();
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is something for me to think about